# How to stop gameobject for being dragged after dragged it once in unity c#

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, unity-game-engine

I want to freeze gameobject after dragging it to the right position using OnMouseDrag

Comment: Any detail.. How you implement your drag... OnMouseDrag? Any Rigidbody on it? Otherwise no one can answer this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of way doing that. I assume you move everything from script, so wherever you update the position of an object, you can stop it from updating with a simple if statement.

In pseudo code:

```
void Update(){
    if(isInRightPosition(yourGameObject) == false){
        you are free to update the position
    }else{
        do nothing and the object will remain in same position;
    }
}
```

`bool isInRightPosition(yourGameObject){
   return yourConditionalExpression;
}`

if that doesn't work, because you are using some other tool to update the position of your object you can also save the right position for the object locally when it is placed well, and just update it's position on every frame in the FixedUpdate function if it involves physics or in the Update function if it does not So even if the user would like to move it, your code will reset it.

So your Update function would be similar to that

C# code now:

`Vector3 lockedPosition = new Vector3(myX, myY, myZ);`

```
void Update(){
    Rigidbody rigidbody = GetComponent<RigidBody>();

    if(isInRightPosition(yourGameObject) == true){
         rigidbody.position = lockedPosition;
    }else{
         /*let the player move the object*/
    }
}
```

Also you can apply this logic in the event handler that you use if you want.